# Best way to raise pH without alkali metal?

Tags: acid-base, ph

I have a process that requires pH~14-14.5 to work. I’ve been achieving this with concentrated NaOH solutions, but the Na cations are later causing side reactions which are detrimental.  Is there any organic base/non-alkali base that has the solubility in water and pKa to reach these pH values?

Comment: Do you mean *non-alkali metal*, i.e. non Group I metal? All "bases" are alkalis.

Comment: There's a whole lot of them, so better edit your question quickly, 'cause right now you could get either simple **yes** as an answer or you might find a whole book somewhere.

Comment: Did you try KOH? LiOH?

Comment: K and Li are Alkali metals...

Comment: Mithoron - I'd take a book. You got one?

Comment: Can you say what the process is? Very high pH requires very high concentration; very high basicity may be obtained with unique bases. Maybe there is a way to avoid the side reactions.

Comment: @tungstenbronze What I meant was, you said sodium is a problem, so why blame all alkali metals?  Are they _all_ problems?

Answer (score 3):

**Tetramethylammonium hydroxide**

This is a strong base like NaOH.

See [Behavior of Polyethylene Oxide Based Nonionic Surfactants
in Silicon Processing Using Alkaline Solutions](http://jes.ecsdl.org/content/142/2/621.full.pdf+html) *J. Electrochem. Soc.* 1995   volume 142, 621-627:

> alkaline cleaning solutions based on quarternary ammonium hydroxides such as choline ($pK_b = 0.1$) and tetramethyl ammonium hydroxide ($pK_b = 0$)

and [Ceramic Nanomaterials and Nanotechnology II](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gb9RAAAAMAAJ&q=%22tetramethylammonium%20hydroxide%22%20complete%20dissociation&dq=%22tetramethylammonium%20hydroxide%22%20complete%20dissociation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb9rnMnPLZAhVNyGMKHUjvCO8Q6AEISDAI) which says:

> In this research, tetramethylammonium hydroxide (TMAH) was used, instead of KOH, to adjust pH of the precursor solution to 14.0

Also, [TETRAMETHYLAMMONIUM HYDROXIDE](http://pubs.rsc.org/-/content/articlepdf/1905/ct/ct9058700955) *Journal of the Chemical Society* (1905):

> An estimation of the strength of the base by means of the velocity
>   of saponification of methyl acetate in N/80 solution showed that it was
>   somewhat weaker than sodium hydroxide. The velocity constants obtained at 25 [degrees] were 0.0106 and 0.0115 respectively, so that if the
>   strength of sodium hydroxide is represented as 100, that of tetramethylammonium
>   hydroxide, under the above conditions, will be represented by 92.

Comment: @OscarLanzi this thesis says pKb is zero https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc822794/m2/1/high_res_d/dissertation.pdf

Comment: Now we're good.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I think Wikipedia is wrong.  Another reference says "In this research, tetramethylammonium hydroxide (TMAH) was used, instead of KOH, to adjust pH of the precursor solution to 14.0". https://books.google.com/books?id=Gb9RAAAAMAAJ&q=%22tetramethylammonium+hydroxide%22+complete+dissociation&dq=%22tetramethylammonium+hydroxide%22+complete+dissociation&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb9rnMnPLZAhVNyGMKHUjvCO8Q6AEISDAI

Comment: @OscarLanzi I added better references to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Water solutions of [amines can get to pH+ 12](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/amine1.htm) or so. [Piperidine, $\ce{(CH2)5NH}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piperidine), is about pH 11.

To get much higher pH+ requires somewhat exotic fluorinated organic chemicals, such as [$\ce{9-COO-Me-fluorene}$, $\ce{(4-Me-C6F4)2CHCN}$ or $\ce{(4-Me-C6F4)(C6F5)CHCN}$.](https://www.chemistryworld.com/Pictures/web/c/r/a/Bronsted-table_smaller.jpg) See [Paenurk *et al*, *A unified view to Brønsted acidity scales: do we need solvated protons?*](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2017/SC/c7sc01424d#!divAbstract) and download the PDF for an interesting explanation.

Comment: You shouldn't make a "sentence link" especially with what looks like acids; you mean their salts or what?